# Entity Framework CreateIfNotExists on Database side

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working on a project where there is table called `Groups`.

`Groups` has primary key on the `Id` column which is string but stores GUID.

The project has a mobile app which allows offline data store. So when a group gets created on Mobile app, it first stores the group on local storage of mobile. Then it uses synchronization mechanism to synchronize the local mobile database with the one on server.

So let's say, there is one group with ID `5e77d8be57ee4505afc1d6ceffe9e3f1` stored on mobile local storage which is about to get synchronized, the mobile app will send create request on `POST Groups` and the API will try to create group with following code.... (Simplified one)

```
...
if (dbContext.Groups.Any(s => s.GroupId == group.GroupId))
{
    return;
}

dbContext.Groups.Add(group);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
...
```

The code works fine in most of the scenario but does not when the mobile app sends multiple request to synchronize the same group. In which case, it sometimes throws an error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Groups'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Groups'

My question is, how can I handle this error with a way to `CreateIfNotExists` on the database side?

Comment: `if (dbContext.Groups.Any(s => s.GroupId == group.GroupId))
{
    return;
}` this part already gives you `CreateIfNotExists`, it checks first and then insert, the issue may appear if there are multiple devices sync same Group but it should be so exceptional case that I would say it's not even a real to have it

Comment: @TornikeCholadze - The question here is, how do we handle concurrency?